# I add two numbers with the same way but get different values

Tags: java

the following is the code and I am extremely confused with the results I get.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
bytes[0] = (byte)0xE6;
bytes[1] = (byte)0x1B;
int high = (bytes[1] & 0xFF)*256;
int low = bytes[0] & 0xFF;
double j = high + low;
double i = (bytes[1] & 0xFF)*256 + bytes[0] & 0xFF;
System.out.println(bytes[1] & 0xFF);
System.out.println(bytes[0] & 0xFF);
System.out.println((bytes[1] & 0xFF)*256);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
```

Logically, `i` and `j` are the same but the result I get is quite amazing.

Results:

```
27
230
6912
230.0
7142.0
```

`i` and `j` should be the same but it isn't. I don't know the reason. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Java primitives are signed. When you see stuff like `0xFF` someone doesn't like that. It's a "trick" to get the unsigned value. So -1 (byte) becomes 255 (int).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't equivalent; In java, [the bitwise `&` operator has a lower precedence than the `+` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). So `i` is actually being defined as `((bytes[1] & 0xFF)*256 + bytes[0])& 0xFF`, which evaluates to 230, instead of the intended 7142. Replacing that line with `i = (bytes[1] & 0xFF)*256 + (bytes[0] & 0xFF);` is all you need to do.